# How can I merge PDF before I export from program

Tags: vb.net, merge

How I can merge PDF file in this report to one PDF ..

```
 Private Sub btnShowReport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShowReport.Click

        Dim t = (From a In db.TransHdrs Where a.AccountCode.ToString = "110102994" Select a)
        Try

            If t.Count > 0 Then
                For Each x In t
                    Dim crdoc As New repTransBulk
                    Dim supcrdoc As New repTransBulk
                    Dim ds As New DSTrans
                    Dim dap As New DSTransTableAdapters.SP_TransPrintTableAdapter
                    dap.Fill(ds.SP_TransPrint, x.ID, x.RegGroupID, x.RegUserID, 0)
              Dim crExportOptions As ExportOptions
                    Dim crDiskFileDestionationOptionas As New DiskFileDestinationOptions
                    Dim crFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions
                    Dim strFolder As String = "c:\Temp\" & x.PatientFileNum
                    If Not Directory.Exists(strFolder) Then
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(strFolder)
                    End If
                    crDoc.SetDataSource(ds)
                    crDiskFileDestionationOptionas.DiskFileName = strFolder & "\" & x.TransNum & ".PDF"
                    crExportOptions = crdoc.ExportOptions
                    With crExportOptions
                        .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
                        .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
                        .ExportDestinationOptions = crDiskFileDestionationOptionas
                        .FormatOptions = crFormatTypeOptions
                    End With
                    crdoc.Export()
                    '        MsgBox("Done")
                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many people here willing to help, but please make sure you've showed what you've tried, what didn't work, and the context of your question. Please make sure you've read stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and then edit your question to better attract people's expenditure of time and effort.

Comment: To help, there are open source tools you can use to join PDFs. I believe PDFSharp on SourceForge is one such product.